# Fileheader in double quotes using talend

Tags: talend

I have exported a file with doublequotes but i am unable to add text qualifier in double quotes.

tmysqlinput---tmap---ifileoutputdelimited

Thanks.

Comment: I have exported a file with doublequotes but i am unable to add text qualifier in double quotes for header.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty.  The solution is to handle the header row as just a normal row of data and turn off the header row checkbox.

1a. I like to create a schema defining the output columns. Then , use a tFixed flow input (or similar) to build the the first row of data (your header values  ) , using the defined schema, and output to the file.   The file output component's header row checkbox should be turned off. The shared schema makes it easy to make sure everything matches up .

1b. Alternatively, just build a single string containing the header and write it out as  raw data.

2. Afterward, output rows of actual data to the same file, in append mode, no header, again using the same schema.